# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 instance using TCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp

I have an Ubuntu instance on AWS EC2, with security groups configured to accept all inbound TCP connections for any port. SSH works perfectly well. 
I also checked if the server that I am running from the instance is accepting calls from all IPs. `netstat` gave the following results:

```
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:4406   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1385/multichaind
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      -
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:4407     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1385/multichaind
tcp6  0   0 ::1:4406         :::*        LISTEN   1385/multichaind
tcp6  0   0 :::22            :::*        LISTEN      -
tcp6  0   0 :::4407          :::*        LISTEN   1385/multichaind
```

I want to connect to the `4407` port. I tried connecting it using Elastic IP and the 4407 port but the connection is refused. Also, there are no rules configured in the instance to reject anything. I checked that using `iptables -S` and the output for that is:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Can this be because of the fact that the instance is in N.Virginia region and I am trying to access it from Tokyo?

P.S. For more information on Multichain please see [here](http://www.multichain.com/).

Comment: Are you able to connect to the port `4407` from localhost ?

Comment: *Can this be because of the fact that the instance is in N.Virginia region and I am trying to access it from Tokyo?*   Not unless there is a firewall in Tokyo that is preventing you from accessing it.  And `Connection refused` would not be caused by a security group misconfiguration.  Traffic not allowed by a security group will result in `Connection timed out`.

Comment: @rolindroy Yes, I am able to connect to the port locally.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the clue, I will check if there is any firewall blocking my requests.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How did you solve it? I have tried disabling the firewall in the instance but could not connect using tcp port. But, i could easily connect using SSH on port 22.

Comment: @SetuBasak The problem was with the internal network that I was connected from. That network had restricted access to TCP ports. Probably if you too are inside some institutions network, it might be the same problem.